# передача данных пакетами в сетях

Tags: сеть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(ВОПРОС)Какой смысл передавать данные пакетами, а не целыми файлами, если время передачи данных по сети одно и тоже, как пакетами так и целыми файлами. только в случая сбоя и передачи всего файла заново целиком пакеты имеют смысл.

(ПРЕДИСЛОВИЕ)В современных сетях пересылаемые данные делятся на части - пакеты. Дело в том, что чащ всего одна линия связи используется для обмена между несколькими узлами.

(СУТЬ)Если передавать большие файлы целиком, то получится, что сеть будет заблокирована, пока не закончится передача очередного файла.
Если передавать отдельные пакеты, время ожидания сокращается до времени передачи одного пакета(это доли секунды), по сети одноновременно передаются пакеты, принадлежащие нескольким файлам.

Comment: Спасибо за ликбез. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Просвещайся: https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/LARTC/ Особенно, обработка очереди доставляет. :)

Comment: (ВОПРОС)Какой смысл передавать данные пакетами, а не целыми файлами, если время передачи данных по сети одно и тоже, как пакетами так и целыми файлами. только в случая сбоя и передачи всего файла заново целиком пакеты имеют смысл.

Comment: Сеть не знает про существование файлов. По ней передаются пакеты/фреймы. Что в них - вопрос к приложению, которое интерпретирует полученный поток данных. Даже если с точки зрения приложения "передаётся целый файл" - по сети передаются отдельные пакеты. Которые, кстати, могут перепосылаться по запросу, если при сборке на приёмной стороне обнаружены потеря или разрушение части пакетов. Вопрос лишён смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Представьте: Вы качаете фильм из интернета размером около 10 Гб. Скорость соединения оставляет желать лучшего. В таком случае, если передавать файл "целиком", то Вы не сможете передать в сеть и получить из неё ни байта информации до тех пор, пока не докачается Ваш фильм. То есть, в ближайшие 2-3 часа посидеть в соц. сетях, например, Вам не светит. Удобно? Не думаю.

Не только поэтому, но, в частности, и поэтому тоже всё, что передаётся по сети, разбивается на пакеты. Передающее оборудование не видит разницы между пакетами разных приложений, что позволяет **одновременно передавать абсолютно разнородную информацию**, будь то содержимое сообщения в мессенджере или маленькая частичка скачиваемого файла. Да, при таком раскладе суммарная скорость передачи того же объёма данных будет та же, что и при передаче последовательно (может даже и чуть меньше). Но здесь важна не скорость, а возможность параллельной работы. Если хотите подробностей, прочитайте про режим разделения времени в параллелизме.

P.S. В моём ответе представлен только один, наивный и наиболее наглядный, резон разделения информации на пакеты. На деле их в разы больше.